# SetText in TextSwitcher using BaseAdapter

Tags: android, textview, settext, imageswitcher

I have a layout with an `ImageSwitcher`, a thumnail gallery, and a `TextSwitcher`. I would like the `TextSwitcher` to update text based on which thumbnail is selected. I have tried using a baseadapter to update the `TextSwitcher` in a similar manner to how the `ImageSwitcher` updates the images in the `ImageView`, but I am running into a wall here. Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you!

JAVA:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Gallery;
import android.widget.ImageSwitcher;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextSwitcher;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ViewSwitcher;
import android.widget.Gallery.LayoutParams;


public class ImageSwitch1 extends Activity implements
        AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener, ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        setContentView(R.layout.imageswitcher);

        TextSwitcher mTextSwitcher = (TextSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.textSwitcher1);
        mSwitcher = (ImageSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.switcher);
        mSwitcher.setFactory(this);
        mSwitcher.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                android.R.anim.fade_in));
        mSwitcher.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                android.R.anim.fade_out));


        mTextSwitcher.setFactory(this);
        mTextSwitcher.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                android.R.anim.fade_in));
        mTextSwitcher.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                android.R.anim.fade_out));

        Gallery g = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery);
        g.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
        g.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);


    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {
    }

    public View makeView() {
        ImageView i = new ImageView(this);
        i.setBackgroundColor(0xFF000000);
        i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
        i.setLayoutParams(new ImageSwitcher.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

        return i;
    }

    private TextSwitcher mTextSwitcher;
    public class TextAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
        public TextAdapter(Context c){
            mContext = c;
        }
    public int getCount(){
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }
    public Object getItem(int position){
        return position;
    }
    public long getItemId(int position){
        return position;
    }
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

        TextView t = new TextView(mContext);
        t.setText(mText[position]);
        t.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        t.setTextSize(36);
            return t;
        }
    private Context mContext;
    }    


    private ImageSwitcher mSwitcher;

    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return mThumbIds.length;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext);

            i.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
            i.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
            i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            i.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.picture_frame);


            return i;



        }

        private Context mContext;



    }

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        mSwitcher.setImageResource(mImageIds[position]);
        mTextSwitcher.setText(mThumbIds[position]);
    }  





    private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.image1_thumb, R.drawable.image2_thumb, R.drawable.image3_thumb,
            R.drawable.image4_thumb, R.drawable.image5_thumb};

    private Integer[] mImageIds = {
            R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2, R.drawable.image3,
            R.drawable.image4, R.drawable.image5};

    private Integer[] mText = {
        R.string.item1, R.string.item2, R.string.item3, R.string.item4, R.string.item5  
    };


}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/FrameLayout1" android:layout_height="match_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"> 

        <ImageSwitcher android:id="@+id/switcher"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            >
        </ImageSwitcher>

        <Gallery android:id="@+id/gallery"
            android:background="#55000000"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:spacing="16dp" android:unselectedAlpha="0.5" android:layout_height="80dp" />
        <TextSwitcher android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/textSwitcher1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextSwitcher>

    </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be passing a string to `mTextSwitcher.setText(mThumbIds[position]);` 
instead change it to `mTextSwitcher.setText(getText(mText[position]));`

Comment: thanks for your help, that makes sense. I am facing a larger problem with this project in that the textswitcher is throwing an illegal argument exception....different question though

Comment: I found the true error in my code, with your hint I was able to get it working. Have to declare the textview INSIDE the onitemselected method.